# chrome fails with "Illegal instruction" in minimal Centos7+Xvfb

Tags: google-chrome, docker, virtualbox, centos7, xvfb

Chrome used to work on headless centos 7 but now seems to fail to start. Spits out "Illegal instruction" as the only output. Happens for both minimal centos 7 virtualbox and the https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/ docker image. Is there a workaround or something I can do to get this setup to work?

Steps to reproduce:
create a minimal centos 7 virtualbox from here
http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
create a non-root user, I named mine "st_user"

as root do:

```
%>yum install -y epel-release
%>yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
%>cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - \$basearch
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
EOF
%>yum install -y google-chrome-stable

%>nohup /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
%>su - st_user
%>export DISPLAY=:99
%>/bin/google-chrome
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
Illegal instruction
```

No combination of parameters, like --no-sandbox, --disable-gpu, or --user-data improves the situation.

My question is how do I get chrome to work in a minimal centos 7 with Xvfb. Is there a workaround or something else I can do?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add one. My question is how do I get chrome to work in a minimal centos 7 with Xvfb. Is there a workaround or something else I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have fonts installed?

```
yum install liberation-mono-fonts liberation-narrow-fonts liberation-sans-fonts liberation-serif-fonts
```

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=60908&sid=6e5b5c743f897b9b300fe69bbae36337&start=10#p257122

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give it a shot tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: You are right, that is what I was missing. Many thanks!